# creating thread that will call the function thousand times

Tags: c

I want to create a thread in main function that will call the other function 100 times . How can i do this, can any body help me in this problem.

Comment: You need to specify an environment, C does not have threads built-in and the environment often dictates which thread primitives are used.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use pthreads, here's a little something I wrote for an in-company tutorial.
(NB: you haven't told us what env you're on so pthreads might not be right).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 100

void * do_something(void * threadId) {
// do something
 }

 int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

for (int t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
    int ret = pthread_create(&threads[t],NULL,do_something(), (void *)t);
    if (ret) {
        printf("Error in creation of thread. Errno : %d\n",ret);
    }
}
pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

I'm assuming you know how to write a make file for this and how to find the lib(s) to make this work.

Comment: you caused me hours of searching... cause you had a typo using `ptread_create` instead of `pthread_create`...

Comment: I am (actually) truly embarrassed! sorry about that. Shows that you really should do cut-n-paste.

Comment: Well with every mistake we learn... was a long time ago I did a typo check when stumbling across errors. So I will start doing it again :) Lesson learned for both of us :D